# Using keyboard and external numpad in AutoHotInterception

Tags: autohotkey

What I need is to map my keys from external numpad to keys on my keyboard. I've decided to use the AutoHotInterception program from evilC. The overall goal is to be able to use windows mouse keys with my keyboard. I have come to the point where program registers both inputs from my numpad and keyboard and I can type numbers with my keyboard but it doesn't really affect the windows mouse keys.

This is what I have so far:

```
#SingleInstance force
#Persistent
#include Lib\AutoHotInterception.ahk

AHI := new AutoHotInterception()

keyboardId := AHI.GetKeyboardId(0x04D9, 0x8008)
numPadId := AHI.GetKeyboardId(0x0C45, 0x7663)

AHI.SubscribeKeyboard(numPadId, true, Func("KeyEvent"))
AHI.SubscribeKeyboard(keyboardId, true, Func("KeyEvent"))

return

KeyEvent(code, state){
ToolTip % "Keyboard Key - Code: " code ", State: " state    
if (state) & (code=30)
{
    Send, {NumpadUp}
}
}

^Esc::
    ExitApp
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you need to send input at hardware driver level to trigger WMK.

Then I'd like to say that your questions seems quite weird. It seems to contradict itself?
You want to remap keys from the external keyboard, but then you also say that you just want to use the numpad with your main keyboard? So what is the external keyboard for actually?

In any case, Here's some advise and a revised script you can probably adapt for your own use. So firstly there's really no need to subscribe to the whole keyboard. Just subscribe to the keys you want.

And since I'm quite unclear on what it is you're actually trying to do, I'll just show an example of how you'd remap <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd> and <kbd>D</kbd> to <kbd>Numpad1</kbd>, <kbd>Numpad2</kbd> and <kbd>Numpad3</kbd> at hardware driver level.

```
#include Lib\AutoHotInterception.ahk

AHI := new AutoHotInterception()

;kind of optional 
;if you don't switch up stuff, you'll always have the same id
keyboardId := AHI.GetKeyboardId(..., ...)

;binding arguments to the function object to make use of the same function over and over
;so don't need to define a new function for each key
AHI.SubscribeKey(keyboardId, GetKeySC("a"), true, Func("KeyEvent").Bind(GetKeySC("numpad1")))
AHI.SubscribeKey(keyboardId, GetKeySC("s"), true, Func("KeyEvent").Bind(GetKeySC("numpad2")))
AHI.SubscribeKey(keyboardId, GetKeySC("d"), true, Func("KeyEvent").Bind(GetKeySC("numpad3")))
return

;the key argument will be the argument we bound to the function object above
;the AHI library takes care of passing in the state argument
KeyEvent(key, state)
{
    global keyboardId
    AHI.SendKeyEvent(keyboardId, key, state)
}

^Esc::ExitApp
```

Sending input is documented here [here](https://github.com/evilC/AutoHotInterception#sending-keyboard-keys).

<sup><sup>(Side question, any chance you're doing this for OSRS?)</sup></sup>

Comment: Hello, ty so much for the answer. The script unfortunately didn't work. Have you tried to test it yourself? I think the problem may be that I have 65% keyboard that doesn't actually have numpad that's why I bought the external one. That's why this part of the code: .Bind(GetKeySC("numpad1")) cant actually find my numpad key on my keyboard right?

Comment: I don't think that would be it, but I can't really test it either so I can't say. Surely `GetKeySC()` should return an okay scancode at least. Did you notice that I didn't fill in the keyboard id stuff? It was just an example. Also, you could adapt the code so that you send from the external numpad just as well. Just change the keyboard ID.